# Where to make Ajax calls in React flux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a react js app where the user can create a user and then i make a http post to the backend.

i have a action that looks like this

```
export function createUser(name, username, password) {
  dispatcher.dispatch({
    type: "CREATE_USER",
    name,
    username,
    password,
  });
}
```

then in my store i call action and it  triggers a function that makes a http post to the backend that looks like this

```
handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
     case "CREATE_USER": {
     this.createUser(action.name, action.username, action.password);
      break;
     }
      default:
    }
  }
```

should i make the ajax call in the store or in the action it self?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you would want redux-thunk which give you opportunity to create actions which dispatches other actions in async way.

After this you can create an action which make a call to server, and on result dispatch new action which would bring to store new data. For example:

```
getData(param) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(dataRequestAction());

    return fetch(`/data/${param}`)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(data => dispatch(setDataAction(data)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(errroDuringRataRetrieving(err)))
    };
}
```

as you see here you have one action (getData) which actually doesn't change the store, but trigger 'dataRequestAction' which put in to store data that request started. Then if request completed one of action can be triggered:

- setDataAction - if all ok;
- errroDuringRataRetrieving - if request failed.

In this way you can handle ajax via redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should have seperate folder called api. There we will have our all api calls. We can inject those file and call those function where we put our functions which call api and respond action.

Comment: you mean something like this https://github.com/auth0-blog/react-flux-jwt-authentication-sample/blob/gh-pages/src/services/AuthService.js ?

Comment: Exactly. We follow similar. Beacuse It sepeare your api calls from front end. Say toay you are using mongodb. tomorrow you switched to postgress. Then there should be only area of project will change called API. Everything  else will be exactly as it is.